# Cannot open specific HTTPS page with jmeter

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, jmeter

im trying to run a load test on a https page. However i keep getting an error even on a simple GET request. Ive tried opening for example https://www.google.com, and that works fine. Ive tried capturing the request, but nothing seems to be sent. Also when i try to record the https page with the jmeter cert i get the same error.

Opening the same page on http works fine. The page im trying to open is a .Net page. Does anyone know what is wrong? Ive stomped my head against this wall long enough now :(.

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv
>   failed    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

After some further investigation i found out that apparently the server does not support socket version negotiation (comments in jmeter properties file). And after setting property: https.socket.protocols=SSLv3 in the properties file it worked!